# Add a label to checkbox/switch Angular 2

Tags: checkbox, typescript, angular, nativescript

I'm trying to add checkboxes, but I read that it is only possible to use ... and changes the image when it's clicked. However, it's not working (onTap() function). Since  didn't work. My second options is to use switch.

How do I add a label to checkbox/switch ? 
Since this line didn't work:

```
<label><switch [checked]="checked" (tap)="onTap()" align="right"> </switch>Employees </label>
```

My sync.component.ts file:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'nativescript-angular/router';
import {APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "../app.routes"
import ImageModule = require("ui/image");
var ImageSourceModule = require("image-source");

var image1 = new ImageModule.Image();
var image2 = new ImageModule.Image();

image1.imageSource = ImageSourceModule.fromResource("checkbox_checked");
image2.imageSource = ImageSourceModule.fromResource("checkbox_unchecked");
image1.src = "~/checkbox_checked.png";
image2.src = "~/checkbox_unchecked.png";

@Component({
selector: "checkbox",
inputs: ["checked : checked"],
outputs: ["tap"],
template: `

<StackLayout backgroundColor="#b3d9ff" width="300" height="550">

  <Label style="font-size : 20px" text="Choose contacts to sync" horizontalAlignment="center"></Label>
  <switch [checked]="checked" (tap)="onTap()" align="right"> </switch>
  <Label text= "Employees" horizontalAlignment="center"></Label>
  <switch [checked]="checked" (tap)="onTap()" align="right"> </switch>
  <Label text= "Clients" horizontalAlignment="center"></Label>


    <Image
      [src]="checked ? '~/checkbox_checked' : '~/checkbox_unchecked'"
      class="checkbox"
      (tap)="onTap()"
      dock="left"
      width="20" height="20"
      align = "right"></Image>

</StackLayout> `
})

 export class SyncComponent{
 public tap:     EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
 public checked: boolean = false;

 //constructor() { }

 public onTap(): void {
     this.tap.next(this.checked);
 }
 }
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I want those Employees and Client be beside switches/checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

put each Label and Switch tags inside additional StackLayout

```
<StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
   <Label ... />
   <Switch ... />
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look at this page, it tells you what to do.

http://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/switch

All you have to do extra is tell it to go to horizontal, like  this:

```
<StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
   <Switch checked="true"></Switch>
   <Button isEnabled="true" text="This is a Button!"></Button>
 </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [nativescript-checkbox](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-checkbox)

1) install using "tns plugin add nativescript-checkbox"

2 ) register the component

```
import { registerElement } from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";
registerElement("CheckBox", () => require("nativescript-checkbox").CheckBox);
```

check the angular2 nativescript checkbox [repo](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-checkbox)